# Find $\lim_{x\to 1}\int_{x}^{x^2}\frac{1}{\ln {t}}\mathrm dt$.

Tags: improper-integrals

> Find $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$, where
>   $$f(x) = \int_{x}^{x^2}\frac{1}{\ln {t}}\mathrm dt$$

I tried splitting it into two integrals, one from 1 to $x^2$ and the other one from $x$ to $1$. Doesn't matter how I split it, I got zero. Wolfram Alpha has some kind of a different, more sophisticated answer with functions we didn't cover at the lecture.

Comment: What's with all these limit integral questions?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the mean value theorem for definite integrals.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals

Comment: Use inequality for $\ln$.

Comment: Could you explain how you are getting $0$? As is, noone knows what you've tried, which could be of help.

Comment: @md2perpe: Have you tried? With the mean value theorem, you get $\ln \xi$ between $\ln x$ and $\ln(x^2)=2\ln x$, so you don't get an exact answer, you only bound the limit within a factor of 2 (provided it exists).

Comment: @HansLundmark. No, I hadn't tried when I suggested MVT. It was just a suggestion of something that perhaps would work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For $t>0$:
$$\frac{t-1}t\leq\ln t\leq t-1$$
so
$$\int_x^{x^2}\frac{1}{t-1}dt\leq\int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{\ln t}\,dt\leq \int_x^{x^2}\dfrac{t}{t-1}dt$$
with limit $x\to1$ you have answer $\ln2$.

Comment: (+1) This is one of the ways I would have approached it.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your edits.

Comment: No problem :-) No idea why `\le` fails today, unless someone did some funky sneaky mathjax >.>

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: Hm, what a nice inequality you have there. Just noticed the lower bound is equivalent to the upper bound after $t\mapsto1/t$.  Very simple and nice.

Comment: +1, but maybe it's worth pointing out that the reason that one can do $A \le B \le B \Rightarrow 1/C \le 1/B \le 1/A$ is that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are either all positive (if $t > 1$) or all negative (if $t < 1$).

Comment: @Nosrati, could you please explain to me how you arrived at that inequality ?

Comment: $$\ln t=\int_1^t\dfrac{1}{x}\ dx\leqslant \int_1^t\dfrac{1}{1}\ dx=t-1$$ @Tusky and let $t=\dfrac1u$ then
$$\ln\dfrac1u\leqslant\dfrac1u-1=\dfrac{1-u}{u}$$

Answer (score 9):

Substituting $t=e^u$, $\mathrm dt=e^u\mathrm du$, we have
$$ f(x)=\int_{\ln x}^{2\ln x}\frac{e^u\mathrm du}{u}.$$
For $x>1$ we then have $1\le e^u\le x^2$, hence 
$$ \int_{\ln x}^{2\ln x}\frac{\mathrm du}{u}\le f(x)\le x^2\int_{\ln x}^{2\ln x}\frac{\mathrm du}{u}$$
(and similar for $x<1$)
with a now well-known integral: $\int \frac{\mathrm du}u=\ln |u|+C$. We conclude that 
$$ \ln 2\le f(x)\le x^2\ln 2$$
and so
$$\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=\ln 2.$$

Answer (score 8):

**HINT:**

Write $\frac{1}{\log(t)}=\left(\frac{1}{\log(t)}-\frac{1}{t-1}\right)+\frac{1}{t-1}$.  Then note that $\frac{1}{\log(t)}-\frac{1}{t-1}$ has a removable discontinuity at $t=1$, which once removed, is analytic in a neighborhood of $t=1$.

Then write,

$$\begin{align}\int_x^{x^2}\frac{1}{\log(t)}\,dt&=\int_x^{x^2}\left(\frac{1}{\log(t)}-\frac{1}{t-1}\right)\,dt+\int_x^{x^2}\frac{1}{t-1}\,dt\tag1
\end{align}$$

Comment: You mean $1/\log(t)$ on the left-hand side?

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks Hans!  Yes, I sure did.  I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Use the fact that $\ln$ is a concave function, and thus, for $1\leq x\leq t\leq x^2$,

$$2(t-1)\frac{\ln(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)}\leq\ln(t)\leq t-1$$

Invert this:

$$\int_x^{x^2}\frac1{t-1}~\mathrm dt\leq\int_x^{x^2}\frac1{\ln(t)}~\mathrm dt\leq\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{2\ln(x)}\int_x^{x^2}\frac1{t-1}~\mathrm dt$$

These are easy to integrate:

$$\int_x^{x^2}\frac1{t-1}~\mathrm dt=\ln(x+1)$$

And so by the squeeze theorem, one can show that

$$\lim_{x\to1}\int_x^{x^2}\frac1{\ln(t)}~\mathrm dt=\ln(2)$$

Noting the right integral mess can be fixed up with the first inequality applied one more time and using the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 5):

$\frac{1}{\ln(t)}=\frac{t}{t\ln(t)}=\frac{(t-1)+1}{t\ln(t)}=\frac{t-1}{t\ln(t)}+\frac{1}{t\ln(t)}$

Let $f : t \mapsto \frac{t-1}{t\ln(t)}$ and $g : t \mapsto \frac{1}{t\ln(t)}$.

- $f$ can be continuously extended in 1, thus $\int f(t) ~\mathrm{d}t$ converges. Then, $\int_x^{x^2} f(t) ~\mathrm{d}t \underset{x=1}{\rightarrow}0$.
- $g(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(\ln(\ln(t))$, and $\ln(\ln(x^2))-\ln(\ln(x))=\ln(2\ln(x))−\ln(\ln(x))=\ln(2)$

Conclusion: the limit is $\ln(2)$.

Comment: $\ln\ln(x^2) - \ln \ln x  = \ln(2 \ln x) - \ln \ln x = \ln 2 + \ln \ln x - \ln \ln x = \color{red}{\ln 2}$

Comment: You're right corrected

Comment: Note that you can write common functions using `\ln` or `\sin`. This makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a good problem for generalization, since the proof for the general result might actually be easier. Suppose $f$ is continuous near $1,$ $f(1)=0,$ and $f'(1)\ne 0.$ Then

$$\tag 1 \lim_{x\to 1} \int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{f(t)}\,dt = \frac{\ln 2}{f'(1)}.$$

With $f(t)= \ln t,$ we get the answer of $\ln 2$ for the given problem.

Rough sketch of proof of $(1)$:

$$\frac{1}{f(t)} = \frac{1}{t-1}\cdot \frac{t-1}{f(t)}.$$

Now the second fraction has limit $1/f'(1)$ as $t\to 1.$ So given $\epsilon>0,$ this fraction lies between the constants $(1-\epsilon)/f'(1)$ and $(1+\epsilon)/f'(1)$ for $t$ close enough to  $1.$ Move those constants outside the integral, evaluate the easy integral remaining, and the result follows.

Comment: There is an error in the anlaysis.  $$\int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{t-1}\,dt=\log(x+1)$$ The limit as $x\to 1$ is $\log(2)\ne 2$.  The result of the generalization is $\frac{\log(2)}{f'(1)}$.

Comment: Right, thank you, I actually knew that, but $\ln 2$ magically and tragically turned into $2.$

Comment: And $f'(1)$, not $f'(0)$, right?  ;-)) ... Two magical transforms don't make a right, but three rights do make a left.

Comment: Yes, this is hilarious. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.   Shall we keep these comments for comical effect?  Or shall I delete like a good old MSE user.

Comment: :O I hope more people see this one.  (+1) I like it very much.

Comment: @MarkViola Leave them up! It's good fun and instructive for readers. I had the idea and then paid no attention to details. Also I had written $f'(1)=0,$ now corrected on my own. It's called author's blindness.

Comment: "Author's blindness?"  I don't see it.

Comment: This is great stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Setting $t = e^s$ we get
$$
f(x) 
= \int_{\ln x}^{2 \ln x} \frac{e^s}{s}\ ds
= \int_{\ln x}^{2 \ln x} \frac{1+s+O(s^2)}{s}\ ds
= \int_{\ln x}^{2 \ln x} \left(\frac{1}{s}+1+O(s)\right) \ ds \\
= (\ln(2 \ln x) - \ln(\ln x)) + (2\ln x - \ln x) + O((\ln x)^2) \\
= \ln 2 + \ln x + O((\ln x)^2) 
\to \ln 2
$$
as $x \to 1$.